# ImageMagick heroku nodejs error

Tags: node.js, heroku, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am getting this error on convert of the imageMagick it was working yesterday so not sure what happened during yesterday to todays deployment that has broken it...

```
 Error: Command failed: convert: error while loading shared libraries: liblcms.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use node.js with heroku and this is the code where the error is thrown from:

```
im.resize({
                        srcPath: tmp_path,
                        dstPath: targetPathSmall,
                        width: 512,
                        height: 512
                    }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                        if(err) {
                            throw err
                        } else {
```

Not sure what needs to be changed since it is on the heroku server...

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Heroku? It sounds like a very app-specific problem.

Comment: I am using a different module and getting rid of imagemagick